# Can't listen to event sent from feathers server to client

Tags: javascript, socket.io, postman, feathersjs

I'm building a server which uses *feathers* and *socketio*.

I'm trying to use feathers channels mechanism to notify relevant users (connections) on relevant events.
Users belong to groups, so upon connecting to the server, I add the connection to the appropriate channels.
Upon publishing, inside `app.publish`,
I'm getting the right data and see that the connection is attached to the channel, but can't figure out how to listen to it on the client.

This is a simplified `channels.js`:

```
app.on('connection', async (connection) => {
    connection.userGroups.forEach((group) => {
        app.channel(`group.groupId`).join(connection);
    }
    app.channel('1').join(connection); // dummy channel
}

app.publish((data, context) => {
    console.log(app.channel('1')); // output shown below
   
    return app.channel('1');
});
```

I'm using Postman as the client, sending a `patch` request, and listening to event named `rooms patched` (rooms is my service name) as described in [feathers docs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.html#listening-to-events). No event is arriving.
If I'm using the raw *socketio* instance and emitting from there, everything seems to work fine and I get the event in the client

```
app.io.sockets.in('some room').emit('rooms patched', data);
```

but as I understand it, it overrides the whole mechanism of channels.

By examining the output from app.publish

```
Channel {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    empty: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function (anonymous)] }
  },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  connections: [
    {
      provider: 'socketio',
      headers: [Object],
      userInfo: [Object],
      userGroups: [Array]
    }
  ],
  data: null,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

we can see that the connection **is** there.

Can anyone help me figure this problem out?

Comment: Can you show us how you are setting up Postman as the client? Also show us complete channels.js?

Comment: Found my mistake, I accidently typed the channel name sorrounded by backticks, where it should have been a plain string variable as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a typo

```
app.channel(`group.groupId`).join(connection);
```

instead of

```
app.channel(group.groupId).join(connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does a port need to be opened on the clients end to create the channel so the communication line is 2 ways. Perhaps javascript will have some code to open up the clients port.